# how to use splitButton in kendo-ui editor toolbar

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-editor

Kendo tool bar has a "splitButton" type but I can't figure out how to use it in an editor toolbar.

just adding one item in tools array does not show it at all

```
{
  type: "splitButton",
  text: "Insert",
  menuButtons: [
      { text: "Insert above", icon: "insert-up" },
      { text: "Insert between", icon: "insert-middle" },
      { text: "Insert below", icon: "insert-down" }
  ]
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think **kendo toolbar** and the **toolbar** inside **kendo editor** is **NOT** the same (please correct me if i'm wrong), and split Button is not an option there. From the [docs](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/editor/configuration/tools) tools array has some options (which you can read on the docs link i provided)

One way to do that is

1. use custom template
2. initiate the toolbar
3. and create event handler that has reference to the kendo editor
4. and you need to take care of the styling too.

(this is what i made up, not sure if it is what you need), check this [**example**](https://dojo.telerik.com/AYIcAmEk)

Comment: Wow! this is great! You made your own toolbar as a custom template. Thanks!

Comment: if you think this answer do it, please accept so that other people also can see it. cheers